# Mandarin equivalent of 後尾 (in the end)?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you often say "後尾" to mean "in the end."

What's the Mandarin equivalent of 後尾? Is it 最後？

Comment: I think 後尾 means 之後 (after); and  "in the end." in Cantonese is "最後"

Comment: 后尾 bkrs:后面，次序在后的部分。
如：「这主角开头表演得极为精彩，但到了后尾，却表现不佳。」
 
后面；末尾。at the end    在终点; 终了时; 最终，最后

 
后尾儿
后尾布局
后尾式
后尾式构型
后尾灯线束总成
后尾箱
后尾翼
ichacha:后尾灯    qf125-w-w; qf150-e-w; tail lamp
后尾儿    [口语] (最后的部分; 后边) behind; back; rear
后尾蚴    metacercaria
风雷后尾灯    qf125-u-w
后尾灯支架    strw
后尾式构型    dart configuration
后尾轴管    rear stern tube
后尾蚴
后尾轮支架

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**广州话普通话** defines 後尾 as

> 粵
>
> 表示時間或空間上居後

with two sample sentences

> 佢後尾卒之簽咗字
>
> 他最後終於還是簽字了

> 佢排隊排到最後尾。
>
> 他排隊排到最末尾。

**广州话方言词典** starts of with pronunciation

> hau6 mei5

and it has the first definition:

> 1 後來；最後

with one example sentence in Cantonese and Mandarin

> 佢後尾點樣ǜ？
>
> 他後來怎樣了？

and one Cantonese example:

> 後尾大家都同意。

definition two:

> 2 末尾；最後（指位置）

and one example sentence:

> 最後尾樖係李樹。
>
> 最末尾的那棵是李樹。

it also lists pronuncation:

> hau1 mei1

and defines it as:

> 後來；最後；後面

with two sample sentences in Cantonese and Mandarin:

> 佢後尾點呀？
>
> 他後來怎麼樣了？

> 你高, 企後尾啦。
>
> 你高, 站在後面吧。

Depending on the context you could choose something like 最后、末尾、后来、后面.